# Convert DefaultMarker to Bitmap

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

location is a png image located in the Resources folder and I am converting it to a bitmap. It works!

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.location1).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

My question is, how to convert the following default marker to bitmap.

`BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueBlue)`

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do that?  More info please.

Comment: I need bitmap of the `BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueBlue)`

Comment: Why do you need that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to use this bitmap to add a text on it. I could able to add a text on it, with custom image. But I want to use Android Default marker which is standard.

Comment: usually you put the text in the InfoWindow.  Not much room for text in the small marker.....

Comment: I am adding is only a single digit integer on the Icon. Space is not an issue for my case.